# Exception thrown when calling 'Properties.Settings.Default.Save()' in C#,

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

My application threw an exception in one particular PC when it tried to save some user configuration settings by calling 'Properties.Settings.Default.Save()'.

The exception is: "Failed to save settings: An error occurred loading a configuration file:
Unable to open file 'C:\Users\xbblmoo\AppData\Local......\user.config'  for writing because it is read-only or hidden".

This problem only happens at one particular PC. I checked that the login user has administrator right. The environment is Windows 7 32-bit.

This problem doesn't happen at another PC with the same environment.
Running the application via VS2008 in that PC was fine though.

Any idea please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the attributes of the file? Is it indeed read-only or hidden?

Comment: can you verify that the file is not set to read-only or hidden?

Comment: @HansPassant, not cool..

Comment: @Apostrofix, I think he means that the disk might be damaged...

Comment: @Apostrofix & Thomas :Thanks for your reaponse.It is set as readonly.i removed it.Its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that "user.config" is not hidden, system etc - reset it's attributes or even delete it.